# How to return an NVCHAR string from SQL formatted correctly

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ssms

In our business we have a program which with functions we can return merge fields for emails and letters that the system generates.

I am trying to write one with a cursor using `NVCHAR` but am having issues with the output for a list of invoices, the section that creates the string is:

```
BEGIN
    IF ( @Schedule <> '' )
        BEGIN
            SET @Schedule = @Schedule + CHAR(10) + CHAR(13);
        END;

    SET @Schedule = @Schedule + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @InvoiceDate, 103)
        + ' | ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), @InvoiceNumber) + CHAR(9) + ' | '
        + CONVERT(VARCHAR(600), @InvoiceDescrip) + CHAR(9) + ' | '
        + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @InvoiceAmount) + CHAR(13);
END;
```

Now because the invoice numbers and description can be different lengths the output it gives to the merge field is as follows:

```
09/06/2014 | 1568        | Item 248              | 100.00
01/08/2014 | 123         | Item 23               | 100.00 
18/08/2014 | Inv #12345  | Warehouse machine     | 2000.00
```

what I'm looking for is the output to be as follows:

```
09/06/2014 | 1568        | Item 248              | 100.00
01/08/2014 | 123         | Item 23               | 100.00
18/08/2014 | Inv #12345  | Warehouse machine     | 2000.00
```

Hopefully the question makes sense, I've searched elsewhere but can't seem to find something that relates to this.

Appreciate any help anyone can offer on this.

Comment: Which dbms product is this? (Tag product used...)

Comment: If you are using Oracle databse(higher versions like oracle 10g,11g etc), then size allocated for nvarchar and varchar is different on those platforms. So do not assume varchar=nvarchar in higher oracle version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SET @Schedule = @Schedule + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @InvoiceDate, 103)
        + ' | ' + CONVERT(CHAR(50), @InvoiceNumber) + CHAR(9) + ' | '
        + CONVERT(CHAR(600), @InvoiceDescrip) + CHAR(9) + ' | '
        + CONVERT(CHAR(10), @InvoiceAmount) + CHAR(13);
```

Change varchar to char of max length that you thing the data will be of. Char will make sure data is of a fixed length.